# Erro 403 na solicitação via $.ajax ao instagram

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, instagram-api

Alguém sabe porque essa solicitação via ajax da erro 403 e na URL funciona normalmente?

O instagram alterou a api deles e achei esse código que serve como uma paginação nas midias, quando faço a requisição via ajax ele da erro (403 - proibido) e quando faço a requisição via url do navegador funciona normalmente.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=472f257a40c653c64c666ce877d59d2b&variables={"id":"3937127813","first":12,"after":"AQDiT0FqVoPQ_0vSPXYUwAIBPCvt8Iw3KpsqYvixKzVDAstuZkHRyAMHo3NgnI2q1ygiLq-5PJ0TCe8daBbEy1RgkIVhY4aECXdwSZnwyWtpbQ"}',
    method: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',

    success: function (retorno) {
        console.log(retorno);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Você precisa está logado ou precisa enviar os cookies na requisição

Comment: tem alguma exemplo para me passar? @ValdeirPsr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iniciar o chrome assim:

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security
```

Não vai resolver o problema dos usuários que acessarem seu site, isso só resolve o problema do seu navegador proprio, ainda sim o script não vai funcionar para outras pessoas devido ao [**CORS**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Controle_Acesso_CORS), ou seja por segurança você não irá conseguir acessar diretamente.

### Instagram API esta obsoleta e será descontinuada

Antes de mais nada conforme a página https://www.instagram.com/developer/ a API que esta usando é obsoleta e provavelmente em breve não será mais funcional, provavelmente em 11, Dezembro de 2018.

A API que deve usar agora é a https://developers.facebook.com/products/instagram/

### Usando a nova API do Instagram

"Infelizmente" não é só pegar e sair usando tem que primeiro seguir os passos descritos em:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started

E provavelmente o teu app vai ter que passar por uma avaliação antes de ficar funcional, pela propria equipe do facebook.

Creio que o que você vai precisar é isto: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/insights para trazer os conteudos, no entanto já lhe deixo avisado, via Ajax não será possivel usar, terá que usar com alguma linguagem do lado do servidor que faça a requisição HTTP direto na API do facebook, por exemplo PHP, asp.net, Django (python), etc.